# How can I tile windows to the top and bottom half of my screen using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, tiling

I have my screen rotated by 90 degrees (vertical orientation). The default Ubuntu keybindings only support left and right half tiling. I tried compiz, but it didn't work.

How can I configure Ubuntu to allow me to retile my windows to the top and bottom half of my screen with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Tiling Assistant](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3733/tiling-assistant/) extension. I recommend installing it using the Extension Manager, which you can install by opening a terminal and running this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

After installing Extension Manager do the following:

1. Open Extension Manager and click the *Browse* tab.
2. Search for "tiling assistant" and click *Install* to install the extension (I have already installed it in the screenshot):

   [image: Extension Manager - Search]
3. Go to the *Installed* tab and press the cog button next to *Tiling Assistant* to open the extension's settings:

   [image: Extension Manager - Installed extensions]
4. In the window that opens, click the *Keybindings* tab and scroll to *Edge tiling*:

   [image: Tiling Assistant - Keybindings tab]
5. Change the shortcuts for *Tile to top* and *Tile to bottom* to the shortcuts of your choice.
6. You should now be able to use these shortcuts to have your windows tiled to the top and bottom halves of your screen. You can also do the same by dragging a window with your mouse to the top or bottom edge of your screen.